# Using Vuesax with Vue | Error: Cannot find module 'stylus'

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Hello i am trying to use vuesax with vue but im running into the error below

[image]

my main.js;

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'
import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' //Vuesax styles

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.use(Vuesax, {
// options here
})
```

[image]

Comment: I can help you more easily if you tell me exactly how hard it is. Vuesax has documentation in its website, you should check.

Comment: did you installed it? `npm i stylus`?

Comment: yes i did.. ;this is my whole package json file. please note i am just copying the templates from the documentation.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 2):

You need to install stylus-loader with stylus like this - "npm install stylus-loader stylus --save-dev". Try this, it will work.
Follow the link to know more "https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-loader"